# CPanel cron job - taking UK's DST into account

Tags: cron, cpanel

Is there a way to take the UK's daylight savings time (GMT vs BST) into account when setting up a cron job in cPanel (hosted with GoDaddy if it makes any difference)?

I doubt it, and it's not important... but would be nice if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cron reads from the `TZ` parameter, so you could change the `TZ` every 6 months to GMT/BST, or just force it to always be UTC.

Also, changing `TZ` requires a reboot, which you won't have access to do.

Comment: Thanks @Spikey - I didn't think it would be possible, but good to have it confirmed